# Let $L(x)=a\,x+b$, What values of $a$ and $b$ makes $L^{[n]}(x)$ converge as $n\rightarrow \infty$.$\forall x\in R$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-iteration

Let $L(x)=a\,x+b$, What values of $a\neq0$ and $b$ such that

$L^{[n]}(x)$ converge as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $L^{[n]}(x)=L(L(...L(x))$ ($n$ times)

$\forall x\in R$?

Comment: a must be less than or equal to 1 for sure.

Comment: A necessary condition is for y=ay+b where y is the limit value. That is, y=b/(1-a).

Answer (score 1):

As @Alephnull pointed out, for fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $L^{[n]}(x)$ converges when $n\to\infty$ then it must converge to $\frac{b}{1-a}$. The key idea here is to write
$$
L(x)-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(x-\frac{b}{1-a}\right),
$$
for it leads to
$$
L^{[n]}(x)-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(L^{[n-1]}(x)-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)=\cdots=a^n\left(x-\frac{b}{1-a}\right).
$$
This tells us that

$\bullet$ If $|a|>1$ then $L^{[n]}(x)$ will NOT converge except for $x=\frac{b}{1-a}$.

$\bullet$ If $a=-1$ then (for fixed $x$) $L^{[n]}(x)$ is sign-oscillating and therefore won't converge, except again for the trivial case $x=\frac{b}{1-a}.$

$\bullet$ Finally, if $|a|<1$ then we can estimate
$$
\left|L^{[n]}(x)-\frac{b}{1-a}\right|\leq|a|^n\left|x-\frac{b}{1-a}\right|,
$$ 
which (for fixed $x$) converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

To sum it up: $L^{[n]}(x)$ converges (and it converges to $\frac{b}{1-a}$) as $n\to\infty$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $|a|<1$.